# Looking for regex: soft hyphen or not a word character

Tags: javascript, regex, soft-hyphen

I am looking for a regex yielding to characters which are not word-characters nor a soft hyphen (U+00AD).

This will give me characters which are not word-characters:

```
((?=\W).)
```

But what about the soft hyphen character? **What is the correct regex?**

Comment: no, this does not work, i am not looking for hyphen but "soft hyphen" - that is a different character (U+00AD see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ad/index.htm)

Comment: to be honest - i do not have to

Comment: You would have to use a hex escape for U+00AD.  Note that Javascript is broken with respect to word characters or anything that isn’t stoneage ASCII — which includes U+00AD.  If someone writes `"élève"` then you are going to be in big trouble whether they have a soft hyphen in there or not. [Javascript is absolutely the worst possible language for writing regexes for non-ASCII strings.](http://training.perl.com/OSCON2011/index.html) Basically, you are severely screwed. Try writing a pattern for `"é-lève"` or `"ja-la-pe-ño"` in Javascript, where those real hyphens are actually soft ones. NFW.

Comment: @tchrist: luckily i am only interrested in the soft hyphen character itself not any special character around that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
[^\w\u00AD]
```

(NOT a word or soft hyphen)

I created a quick and dirty `last_symbol()` function:

```
function last_symbol(str) { 
    var result = str.match(/([^\w\u00AD])[\w\u00AD]*$/); 
    return (result == null) ? null : result[1]; }

last_symbol('hello')   // null
last_symbol('hell!')   // '!'
last_symbol('hell!o$') // '$'
```

Comment: what do i need to set if i want the last occurence of this?

Comment: @Thariama The last character or the last group of characters matching this?

Comment: the last character, but [\w\u00AD]+$ should be the one

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\u00AD` to match the unicode soft hypen character, so you should be able to negate this expression and combine it with `\W` to match characters which are not a word character and not a soft hyphen.

```
[^\u00AD\w]+
```

Comment: well, i am looking for the full regex

Comment: @Thariama What exactly are you trying to match?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex `/\x{AD}/u` to match soft hyphens in PHP!